# Adaptivecard with 2 actions (Accept/Decline)

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

Can someone help how to handle 2 submit actions in an adaptive card?
If the user clicks on the acceptbutton, another dialog must start.
If the user clicks on the declinebutton, the restart dialog has to start.

The json layout

```
        "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Accept",
            "data": { "choice": "Accept"}
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Decline",
            "data": { "choice": "Decline"}
        }
    ]
```

Code:

```
bot.dialog('overview', function (session, options) {
    if (session.message && session.message.value) {
        if(choice == "Accept"){
            session.beginDialog('otherDialog');
        } else if (choice == "Decline"){
            session.beginDialog('restart');
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using other features of adaptive cards in your card, or could you maybe use a  `PromptDialog`?

Comment: Can you post the complete code that shows how you are sending the adaptive card (and the complete adaptive card JSON - not a snippet)?

Comment: Have you considered using a `builder.Prompt.confirm()` (aka choice prompt) instead? This is the simplest way to handle a binary choice workflow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt

Answer (score 1):

**choice** will be a property on **.value**

```
bot.dialog('overview', function (session, options) {
    if (session.message && session.message.value) {
        session.endDialog();
        switch (session.message.value.choice) {
            case 'Accept':
                session.beginDialog('otherDialog');
                break;
            case 'Decline':
                session.beginDialog('restart');
                break;                
          }             
        return;
    }else{
        //show the card, since there has not been a choice
        var cardMessage  = require('./overviewCard.json');
        cardMessage.address = session.message.address
        bot.send(cardMessage)
    }
})
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to work, i'm going to change it to a prompt because i've been stuck on this for weeks. All you guys, thanks for the help!